# What elements of my group am I missing and which group is it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, group-theory, representation-theory

I am working on an exercise which is asking to find the elements of the symmetry group of the following figure given below:[image: Rectangular box with a square base]

Note that the rectangular sides of the box all have the exact same pattern where the left half is grey and the right half is white.

If I consider $c$ to be the rotation of the figure around the z-axis (axis being perpendicular to the square base and top of the rectangular box) and $b$ to be the reflection on the $x-y$ plane (plane formed by the $x$ and $y$ axis which are both perpendicular to the vertical rectangular sides), I have figured out that $$c^4=e, b^2=e, (bc^2)^2=e$$.

I thought the element of my group would be $${e,c,c^2,c^3,b,bc,bc^2,bc^3}$$ which is the group $D_4$, but knowing that $bc^2bc^2=e$ I can only find $cb=c^3bc^2$ and I cannot find an expression to commute $c$ and $b$. That mean that I am missing elements on the group.

What elements would form my group and which group would it be?

Comment: Seems more like a question for [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just working out an example, it seems to me that $c b = b c^3$. In other words, looking at the square from the top, a reflection followed by a clockwise rotation, is equivalent to three clockwise rotations (or one counter clockwise rotation) followed by a reflection.

Comment: I think you are refering to a reflection on a different plane from mine. If I do the operations you mentioned on my definition of reflection (see above I reflect over the $x-y$ plane), I do not get that the operations you said are equal. @Andrew

Comment: sorry but i do not have enough score to post an image on Math SE @NiharKarve

Comment: I think a reflection through the $xy$ plane should simply commute with rotations about the $z$ axis.

Comment: But then if they indeed commuted, wouldn't the first relationship you mentioned in your comment $cb=bc^3$ not hold anymore? @Andrew

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood your question and thought the reflection was through the $xz$ or $yz$ plane. Reflections through the $xy$ plane are easier.

Comment: you said that they commuted if the reflection was on the $xz$ or $yz$ plane. Do they commute if the reflection is on the $xy$ plane? Could you elaborate more on what elements would I find in the symmetry group if you know? @Andrew

Comment: The reflection and rotation **don't** commute if the reflection is through the $xz$ or $yz$ plane. That is the case where $cb=bc^3$. The reflection and rotation **do** commute if the reflection is through the $xy$ plane. This is not difficult to prove. Put labels "a, b, c, d" on the corners of the top plane of the box, and "A, B, C, D" on the corners of the bottom plane of the box, and try doing a few examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, if I found that $bc=cb$, then the group will be abelian. From $c^4=e$ and $b^2=e$, the elements of the group are the same elements as in $D_4$  (the groups are not the same though, since $D_4$ is not Abelian). I was asked to construct the character table, which would consist of 8, 1 dimensional irreps with 8 conjugacy classes, with a total of 64 elements in the character table. This seems to be very complicated for an exam question, so is there anywhere I went wrong? @Andrew